# How to handle error location in gin handler function?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have gin API and i want to specify error location.
Let me have the following structure of endpoint:

```
- Gin API
- - Handler func
- - - My_package Func_
- - - - My_package SubFunc
```

To show where the error occurred

1. Adding to its text the name of the function where error occurred
   adding error to gin context

```golang
func SubFunc(c *gin.context) err {
    // some logic
    err := someAction()
    if err != nil {
    err := fmt.Errorf("SubFunc %w", err)
        c.Error(err)
    return err
    }
}
```

2. Middleware logger printing error

```golang
func ErrorHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    c.Next()
    errs := c.Errors.ByType(gin.ErrorTypeAny)
    if len(errs) > 0 {
        c.IndentedJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error_desc": errs[0].Error()})
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Is it a good approach to specify error location?

I tried to specify location of error by traceback (like python)

1. runtime/debug debug.PrintStack
2. github.com/pkg/errors errors.WithStack

But instead of a traceback in my code, I got a trace from golang inner packages.
And I understand that inn't good idea because traceback isn't golang way.

Comment: Errors that get sent back to the client are for users/clients, not for debugging. Debug logging is for the dev debugging the code, so adding the "location" or stack trace info to error responses is not a good idea. For one, if you rely on some DB to store data, errors like this could present a potential attack vector: an error response suddenly contains information on the stack you're using, potentially DB/table names, dependencies used, which may have known vulnerabilities, etc...

Comment: Elias, thank for your advice, I will remove error returning when app will go to production.
But I still need to figure out about good error location handling.

Comment: Use receiver functions, bootstrap your dependencies, and inject a logger instance across your application. `go.uber.org/zap` or something. You can use config to set the log level to `Debug`, write your logs to stderr or some file, etc... Every project I've ever worked on at some level relied on logging to diagnose issues, that's what it's for. Even the kernel of your OS logs warnings, info, and errors... You want to know where an error originated from? `func(s *Service) Something() { s.log.Debug("something went wrong in pkg.Service.Something")}`

Comment: Additionally, if being able to figure out where an error comes from in your code, there's a good chance that you're either using errors that are too generic (not package/domain specific enough), or your code is too tightly coupled (e.g. dependencies of your handlers returning HTTP-style error codes), your code is not tested enough (or not testable enough), and you've not built the project in a way that facilitates easy debugging (using tools like dlv). This is a bit of an X-Y problem

Comment: Elias, yes I want to know where an error originated from. And I ask such question because it seems strange to me to manually write the function name in the error text every time, and I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this in golang.

Comment: Function names are for the benefit of humans, to make reading code easier. We need to be able to read function names when debugging, not when executing code. If your code panics, go will helpfully provide the call stack and line numbers for you. An error is part of your code running, so information as to where it comes from is not relevant. Using specific errors in specific packages goes a loooong way already, but if you insist on having the exact function name, then you'll have to log it yourself.